# Как вывести на канвас картинку (png)?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, photo

Как вывести на канвас картинку (png), так чтоб поверх неё можно было рисовать?
если можно пример.

Comment: `Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myImage.png"));
        graphicsContext.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно работать следующее:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    final static int CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    final static int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;

    Image bgImage;
    double bgX, bgY, bgW = 100.0, bgH = 100.0;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        final GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        initDraw(graphicsContext);

        Group root = new Group();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(canvas);
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 425);
        primaryStage.setTitle("image on canvas");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void initDraw(GraphicsContext gc){
        double canvasWidth = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
        double canvasHeight = gc.getCanvas().getHeight();

        // достаем нужную картинку по какому-то пути.
        // в данном случае из папки с классами достаем accept.png
        bgImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("accept.png"));
        bgX = canvasWidth/2 - bgW/2;
        bgY = canvasHeight/2 - bgH/2;
        gc.drawImage(bgImage, bgX, bgY, bgW, bgH);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Создаем сцену, добавляем канву. Добавляем картинку на `graphicsContext`. Картинку берем оттуда, откуда удобно и как удобно. В данном случае картинка `accept.png` лежит прямо в папке с файлом класса и отобразится прямо по центру.